# Can I switch between desktop environments using terminal?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, command-line, kubuntu

I've installed GNOME desktop on Kubuntu 12.04. But my speed of clicking take me to select Gnome as default desktop. Is there a way to switch from Gnome to KDE using terminal. I tried to Google it but nothing helped me to resolve my problem.

Comment: Actually it is not a problem more like a customization Feature :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 12.04, if you install a new desktop environment via [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal): e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

During the installation the display manager pops up stating that you have more than one desktop environment but that you can only run one.  It then asks you to select a default, so there's your opportunity.

I can't find a way to do it without having to install a new desktop...

Comment: Background:  I was running Ubuntu 11, and had swapped from Unity to Gnome. While upgrading to 12.04, I noticed it mentioned a few things like deprecating Gnome packages, and I didn't pay much more attention.

After the upgrade, it booted into a borked Gnome environment which barely function.  Had to use Terminal to do the above.

So perhaps a word of warning to anyone: upgrade Ubuntu while using Unity, in case it dumps a desktop environment in the process!

Answer (score 2):

no, you log out and at the log in screen select KDE (or whatever you prefer). The log in manager will then keep your new selection as default.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the environment name followed by `--replace` in the terminal. For example `gnome-shell --replace` to quickly swap environments.

Comment: This will just switch between different GNOME-based interfaces; this will not work nearly as well to switch between, for example, GNOME and KDE, since it's not just the shell (`gnome-shell` or `unity` in GNOME) that needs to be replaced by different interface components.